# How can I access `figma.clientStorage` in a Figma Plugin UI?

Tags: figma

In my plugin code (code.ts), I am using the [ClientStorage Figma Plugin API](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/figma-clientStorage/) to store some state.

How can I read data from clientStorage from UI code (ui.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can access clientStorage directly from the UI, but you can pass the stored value from code.ts to ui.html using `figma.ui.postMessage`.

Here is an example of code that is retrieving a value from clientStorage, and sending it to the UI:

```
function retrieveFromStorage() {
  (async () => {
    try {
      var item = await figma.clientStorage.getAsync('item');
      figma.ui.postMessage({ type: 'send-item', payload: item);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }})();
}
```

And then you can access it in the UI like so:

```
if(event.data.pluginMessage.type == 'send-item') {
  var item = event.data.pluginMessage.payload
}
```

In this example I am also using "type" to make sure I am receiving the correct message.